# Do not translate data between double curley braces using Google Translate API

Tags: php, google-translation-api

I Am using Google Translate API V2 to translate my content but I am facing issue when I try to translate Liquid combined stuff ( having some coding tags like {{ }} & {% ... %}. ) I do not want to translate data between these tags.

Is there something I could instruct Google not to translate data between this?

Below is my sample input.

```
Hi{% unless order.customer.first_name == blank %} {{ order.customer.first_name }}{% endunless %}, thanks for your purchase of {{ order.total_price | money }} from {{shop.name}}! {% if order.requires_shipping %}We'll notify you when it ships.{% else %}We'll notify you when it's ready.{% endif %} {% if order.order_status_url %}View order ({{ order.name }}): {{ order.order_status_url }}{% endif %}

Text {{ 'stop' | upcase }} to unsubscribe...
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [google translator toolkit - how to exclude portions of the text from being processed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33942733/google-translator-toolkit-how-to-exclude-portions-of-the-text-from-being-proce)

Comment: Yes thanks, trying the same solution. seems will get solution